# replaceWith does not work with child class

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I cant seem to make replaceWith work with a child class. Should I do this another way?

```
<ul>
<li><input type="text" class="fn" value="Elvis"> <a href="#" class=".rmv" onclick="test()">test</a></li>

<li><input type="text" class="fn" value="Sam"> <a href="#" class=".rmv" onclick="test()">test</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function test() {
$(this).find('.fn').val().replaceWith('Ted')
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as sidenote - you're using the class on the anchor tags wrong - it should be

```
<a href="#" class="rmv">
```

instead of

```
<a href="#" class=".rmv">
```

As you're already using jQuery, you could just attach the `click()` event using jQuery like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".rmv").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev('.fn').val('Ted');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text" class="fn" value="Elvis" /> <a href="#" class="rmv">test</a>

    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" class="fn" value="Sam" /> <a href="#" class="rmv">test</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I applied your example to a project I'm working on and the script is not working perhaps it requires a different method. Since I can not apply a code snippet to comments I provided the following link. I have eliminated all other scripts. The goal is to zero out the quantity using the code snippet you provided. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CliffT I've just made a Fiddle for the new markup: http://jsfiddle.net/03tnn0wc/  . Because now the input is not the previous element, you can just go up to the closest `li` and find the `input` using `$(this).closest('li').find('.qty')`. Also note that the order-test.html isn't valid, there are html, body etc. tags missing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, unfortunately, while this works on the code I provided, it does not work on my master. I'm at witts end on this problem, too many hours. Do you have a way I can contact you directly. Perhaps pay you to review my code?

Comment: @CliffT Thanks for the offer, no need for payment. Like most people on SO I just like to help as SO also helped me a lot throughout the years. Could you just provide a link where it's not working or, if not possible, put the code in question in a Fiddle? Maybe it's again just a minor adjustment because of different markup.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .val() can only be used to get the value of an INPUT tag.

To set the value, you have to use '.val(newvalue)', in your case:

```
$(this).find('.fn').val('Ted');
```

Edit: You may have solved this by now, but for completeness, here are a few more changes to make the jsfiddle script work.

You need to set the Load Type of javascript to 'No wrap' so that `test` is found globally.

Then, using `onclick` on your links you also need to pass the callee object: `test(this)`, to the callback, like this:

```
<li><input type="text" class="fn" value="Elvis"> <a href="#" class=".rmv" onclick="test(this)">
test</a></li>
```

Finally, in order to reference the `<input>` tag and change its value, one way is to look up until the `<li>` tag and then down to `<input class="fn">` with `jQuery` like this:

```
function test(e) {    
   $(e).parents('li').find('.fn').val('Ted');
}
```

With those changes, the value of the `<input>` enclosed in the `<li>` in which the corresponding `<a>` element was clicked is changed to `Ted`.

Comment: You do not even need `find()`. Just use `$('.fn').val('Ted')`.